# SSIS package fails when used in SQL Server Agent (SQL to MySql connection)

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have create a Data Flow Task with ADO NET Source (Local SQL Server), Data Conversion Step and ADO NET Destination (ODBC Provider).

While in BIDS everything works fine, when iam running the package from SQL Server Agent i get the following error:

> "Message
>   Executed as user: ISK\SYSTEM. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 10.50.1600.1 for 32-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2010. All rights reserved.
>       Started:  5:31:26 μμ
>     Error: 2017-08-20 17:31:27.79
>        Code: 0xC0208452
>        Source: Data Flow Task ADO NET Destination [22]
>        Description: ADO NET Destination has failed to acquire the connection {F2EA5342-B616-4E16-80E5-2744574A453A}. The connection may have been corrupted.  End Error  Error: 2017-08-20 17:31:27.79     Code: 0xC0047017     Source: Data Flow Task SSIS.Pipeline     Description: component "ADO NET Destination" (22) failed validation and returned error code 0xC0208452.  End Error  Error: 2017-08-20 17:31:27.79     Code: 0xC004700C     Source: Data Flow Task SSIS.Pipeline     Description: One or more component failed validation.  End Error  Error: 2017-08-20 17:31:27.79     Code: 0xC0024107     Source: Data Flow Task      Description: There were errors during task validation.  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  5:31:26 μμ  Finished: 5:31:27 μμ  Elapsed:  1.622 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed."

I have try everything i could find:

1. Run64BitRuntime - False
2. ProtectionLevel - DontSaveSensitive
3. ExecutionOption of JobStep - Use 32 Bit Runtime
4. Created a package configuration file and set there the connection password   for the mysql database.

I will be more than happy if anyone could point some directions

Comment: What kind of authentication are you using to connect to the destination? 
Have you tried if you could use ODBC/ OLEDB connection instead of ADO.NET?

Comment: Another: Did you try protection level with "encrypt sensitive" with a password?

Comment: Is the package getting executing from IDE? Coming to the SQL Server Agent job, are you using any Proxy to run the job?